# Laravel 7 amd Babel

Tags: laravel, babeljs

I am using laravel 7. How can I use Babel with mix.combine ?
I can find something in the docs but only mentions vue and react automatically using Babel?
I am used tot Gulp and not Webpack. With Gulp I just use it for converting es6 to es5.

Comment: Use laravel mix it also convert es6 to es5 pretty easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel mix is a wrapper around webpack, so using gulp isn't configureable

Seeing as your setup isn't doing much, I would swap to using webpack